# How to assign a variable to another variable in AWK, why this code NOT working?

Tags: bash, awk

Here is the code. I am just trying to print another column with a random value.

```
value=$RANDOM

awk -v numColumns=$numColumns -v value=$value '{
if ($1 !~ /\#/ && $1 !~ /^$/) 
{       
                 $(NF+1) = "$value"
                 print $0
}
}' $infile > $outfile
```

The code prints $value in the last column it adds instead of printing a random number.
This is an ak script inside a bashscript. The file is filename.bsh, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

IMHO passing the random value is not needed. It can be generated inside [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk).

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand();R=int(rand()*32768)}{print $0, R}' <<XXX
one
One Two
ONE TWO THR
XXX
```

Output is:

```
one 31122
One Two 31122
ONE TWO THR 31122
```

If You need a float random value (`[0, 1)`), then this can be used:

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand();R=rand()}{print $0, R}'
```

Output:

```
one 0.878804
One Two 0.878804
ONE TWO THR 0.878804
```

If You need more decimal digits you can use

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf("%.16f", rand())}'
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFMT="%.16f";print rand()}'
```

Maybe You want to add different random number to each line:

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand()}{print $0, int(rand()*32768)}' <<XXX
one
One Two
ONE TWO THR
XXX
```

Output:

```
one 29633
One Two 26052
ONE TWO THR 23050
```

Comment: I would do the same if the random number is only used by awk.

Comment: @Kent: Is it used elsewhere? ;)

Comment: This works! Can i generate a float number instead of int? I can't find a function life float().

Comment: You do not have to! rand() returns a float! I used `int` because `bash` $RANDOM does return an integer in `[0, 32767]`. Use simply `rand()` if you need a float in `[0, 1)` (or `[0, 1[` with different notation)...

Comment: @TrueY I don't know if it is used anywhere, I just read he said the awk is in a shell-script. so it **could** be used by other commands/tools in the script.

Comment: @Kent I am not sure what you mean by 'used elsewhere'. I am sorry if i didn't provide enough info or something else but right now the code works and i am glad :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: @detraveller if you are not sure, it means it was not used elsewhere. :) don't forget to accept the answer which solved your problem

Comment: I did. I think i understand what you meant. I should have generated the random number inside awk. But google told me abt $RANDOM of bash and i started working on that without thinking.

Comment: @detraveller: I thought that `ENVIRON["RANDOM"]` is working. But, of course, it is not as it is just a "virtual" variable. :) On the other hand `rand` is not part of the old [tag:awk].

Comment: rand() is working but generates to 6 decimal places. I need 16 decimal places, is that possible?
I have GNU Awk 3.1.8

Comment: @detraveller: Actually [tag:awk]'s `OFMT` variable defines the output format of a float in `print`. If You modify it in `BEGIN` block to `OFMT="%.16f"`, you will have what you need. I also modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: @TrueY I am assigning a random number with `$NF+1 = rand()`. I am not using print. How can i set rand() to directly give me 16 decimal places? Or how can i do something like `$NF+1 = print rand()`?

Comment: @detraveller: Try `var = sprintf("%.16f", rand())`. But what will you do with this number if You do not print it?

Comment: @TrueY I am of course printing it later. But i am using print $0. And the var does the job here, thanks.

Comment: @detraveller: If you just want to convert numbers to string then this format is controlled by `CONVFMT` variable. Example: `echo solaris|awk 'BEGIN{CONVFMT="%.16f"}{$NF=rand()}1'`; output: `0.2377875122417638`.

Answer (score 1):

try to do the change following:

```
$(NF+1) = "$value"  -> $(NF+1) = value
```

EDIT

fyi:

```
kent$  val=$RANDOM

kent$  echo $val
26521

kent$  echo "a b c d"|awk -v value=$val '{$(NF+1)=value;print $0}'
a b c d 26521
```

Comment: If i use `$(NF+1) = value`, it prints all the columns twice on the same line, don't know why.

Comment: and it prints nothing for the extra column i am adding.

Comment: @detraveller for your current codes, I cannot see it happen... btw, your `numColumns` var is not used at all. I assume that you just copied codes here partially.

Comment: Yes. I am using numColumns in a loop because i want to print as many new columns as the value contained in numColumns. But that variable is working fine in a for loop(i=0; i<numColumns...). The variable $value is the problematic one.

Comment: IMHO setting $(NF+1) is pointless in this case. `print $0, value` does the same.

Comment: @TrueY you are very right! it is just a fix to OP's codes. His problem was the confusion between awk var and shell var.